# LG LSC27910sb refrigerator freezer door water line broken

Tags: refrigerator

Water was leaking, found the line that runs through the freezer door to the dispenser was split.

[image: Picture showing hose split]

I have read the service manual ( http://www.appliancefactoryparts.com/content/pdfs/138598-2.pdf ) and cannot find instructions to replace this line - or any part number. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: A number of DIY repairs for this very common fault on youtube.  Most insert a hose barb if there is enough tube sticking out, some thread a smaller plastic line on the inside, some add an external vinyl tube and hose clamp etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So... the solution from LG is that the door needs to be replaced (~$500 + $100 shipping.) Apparently this model is poorly designed and the dispenser is embedded into the foam insulation and cannot be serviced.

Comment: Might be possible to repair even do, digging it out and then spraying in more foam,  but... For what it's worth, in-doir water and ice dispensers are somewhat notorious for early failures. You might ask a lical service tech whether there's any way to find a "recycled" door that would work.

Answer (score 1):

I see what you mean, I couldn't find anything either. That black collar looks like a push-in connection. See if you can get LG on the phone or a Chat on their website to walk you through extracting it first.

Plan "A" would be to remove the hose after the split & cut a new end at or before the split to just shove it in & be good as new. It's likely very similar to a Sharkbite connection. Where you may have to insert a thin tiny flathead screwdriver (or 2) or a plastic or metal sleeve into that collar about an inch to push up the locking rings for the hose to actually just fall out.

Comment: From LG Service "Regrettably, we only recommend a certified technician to repair this kind of problem especially that we are unable to get the correct part number of the said water line. In this case, we recommend you to go to  so you can locate a service provider in your area and check which one offers the best service price and soonest availability. "

Comment: Yeah, just great. "Sorry about our defective materials, design & execution, but you can just pay more every time this happens & it will keep happening". Well, give the screwdrivers & sleeves a shot. If you can get it out, then get a Shark-bite elbow fitting. You'd cut off a chunk of hose a 1/2" or so longer than the current break's length & put the fitting on, maybe even lock it in place with a crossbar. The elbow would take all the stress & can actually handle it & you'd be able to replace any future lines with very little trouble, but you wouldn't have this particular problem again.